# How to manage different versions of application by using plugins in cakephp 3?

Tags: plugins, cakephp-3.0

I have a single cakephp 3 application

I have a generic view which render data depending of an array struture of fields configured in each Model, this array includes configurations for display each field in the view like (text titles, maxsize, sortable, etc..) and database configuration like (column name in the database/table, datatype, etc..) in the same array, and its working fine.

```
public $tableData = [
    [
        'name' => 'Table1.name',
        'title' => 'Name',
        'field' => 'name',
        'sortable' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
        'size' => '50px',
    ], 
    [
        'name' => 'Asosiation1.option',
        'title' => 'Topic',
        'field' => 'topic_option',
        'sortable' => true,
        'type' => 'string',
        'size' => '150px',
    ],  
    ... More fields and asosiations
]
```

But now, i need to have these same Models in different versions, because the structure of the database/table for each Model change every year, but i need to preserv/show the data corresponding to each version as it is.

So if a user request mySite.com/2010, Site must show data using Model array structure defined for that year especifically.

So, i created:

/plugins/Years/version2010

/plugins/Years/version2011

etc..

and in each pluging, I copied all Models changing only the namespace, defaultConnectionName (1 schema per Year) and array structure.

This provokes to have mutiple plugins loaded in bootstrap config.

> *Is there any way to load only the necesary plugin depending of the request ?(/2010, /2011, etc..)*
>
> Ex. In bootstrap.php I do for each plugin year:
>
> ***Plugin::load('Years/version201X', ['bootstrap' => false, 'routes' => true]);***

also

> *Is there any way to avoid having to specify the plugin name every time i do  loadModel() or TableRegistry::get() ?*
>
> Ex.  In main App GeneralController I have to do every time:
>
> $this->loadModel(**'Years/version201X/Table1'**);

Or maybe there is another better approach to solve this situation i havent seen

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any way to load only the necesary plugin depending of the
>   request ?(/2010, /2011, etc.

Yes. Inside **config/bootstrap.php** you can check the request uri and then have a switch statement for the plugins. Something like this:

```
$uri = filter_input(INPUT_SERVER, 'REQUEST_URI', FILTER_SANITIZE_SPECIAL_CHARS);
// might need explode('/', $uri); to extract the right URL component

switch ($uri) {
    case '2011':
        // load plugin
        break;
    case '2012':
        // log plugin
        break;
}
```

You probably dont even need the switch statement, be creative there. Obviously thats not exact, but if gives you the right idea.

> Is there any way to avoid having to specify the plugin name every time
>   i do loadModel() or TableRegistry::get() ?

If the model is unique to the plugin then I am not sure how you get away with this. Whats the problem though? Just a few extra characters. Sounds like you only have to do this once per year, right? However, you might not have to specify that if you're within the scope of the plugin. I am not sure on that, but its worth trying.